# Code works in Visual Studio 2010 but not in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I've got a VB.Net project that was coded in Visual Studio 2010. The code runs without any errors. If I open the project in Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) a "System.NullReferenceException" is thrown for the following line

```
mcEnd.Visible = False
```

The object is created here:

```
WithEvents mcStart, mcEnd As New MonthCalendar
```

Does anybody have an idea, why Visual Studio 2015 is behaving like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you be able to show more code? Are the two statements in the same block/sub/class/module? To be honest you need to give more detail. Ave a look at this page on asking questions..  It will help us to answer you [ask]..  Cheers..  And welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is actually the case. Kind of weird. But the solution is simple: `WithEvents mcEnd As New MonthCalendar` or even `WithEvents mcStart, mcEnd As MonthCalendar mcEnd = new MonthCalendar`. That is: clearly telling the variable being instantiated. Not sure about the exact reason for this; is it because VS 2015 is new and some corrections are pending? Or is this behaviour plainly not-right enough and will not be supported anymore? Note that the C#/VB.NET compilers have been rewritten and that some of the old "features" haven't been included (because of being wrong).

Comment: The code is in one class, which is inherits a generic form class. The dim statements is on top of the class, whereas the other is the first line in a sub that sets up the monthcalendars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line to

```
WithEvents mcStart As New MonthCalendar
WithEvents mcEnde As New MonthCalendar
```

works fine. Thanks

Comment: This issue appears to be fixed in VS2015 Update 1, released yesterday.